# Application runs, but I can't find the .app file (Pages, Numbers)

Tags: finder, applications, pages, search

If I open up a .pages or .numbers file on my computer (macOS 10.12.4), the respective applications open without delay.

However, when I search for Pages.app or Numbers.app in Finder, I cannot find either application! Neither application is listed in the Applications directory.

Where are these apps located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check where any application is located via the Dock.

Right-click on the app's icon in the Dock and go to Options > Show in FInder.

If you haven't already got Pages and Numbers in your Dock, you don't need to add them. You can still do the above while they're running.

Comment: Ah... thanks, now I feel silly. Both files were in a directory below `Volumes`, and were invisible to search. How strange...

Comment: In which directory were they found? They should begin /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Applications or perhaps /Volumes/Macintosh HD/<user_account>/Applications.

Comment: @IconDaemon They were in a folder directly below /Volumes that had the same name as one of my external hard drives, which had long been unmounted. I don't know why or how they ended up there.

Comment: And have you have moved them back to the /Applications folder where they belong? That's the sensible location.